# django cassandra not executing select query with where clause for datetime range

Tags: python, django, cassandra

I have data in cassandra and I am trying to fetch data from the DB within a datetime range.

Below is the code.

```
fromdate = datetime.combine(dt, datetime.min.time())
todate = datetime.combine(datetime.now().date(), time(23, 59, 59))
print(fromdate)
print(todate)

batch = BatchStatement()
batch.add(SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM datadump WHERE 'pickup_time' >= '%s' AND 'pickup_time' <= '%s' ALLOW FILTERING;"),
              (fromdate, todate,))
data = session.execute(batch)
```

The above code does not work when I try to fetch data within a datetime range but if I try to fetch all the data like "SELECT * from datadump" it works.

Can someone please let me know what's wrong with the above approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I see `ALLOW FILTERING` and that's usually "wrong."  Is `pickup_time` a clustering key?  If so, try specifying all of the keys defined in front of it, especially the partition key(s).

Comment: @Aaron, thanks for the reply. pickup_time is the column name in the DB.

Comment: So it's not a key at all?  That's definitely a problem.  Also, Alex brings up a good point in his answer.  Using a batch with a `SELECT` in Cassandra doesn't make any sense.

Comment: OK, I executed this query directly in the RazorSQL and got the output. SELECT * FROM datadump WHERE 'pickup_time' >= '2020-03-18 00:00:00' AND 'pickup_time' <= '2020-03-18 23:59:59'; But what am I missing in the code? Also, I have changed the code to stateMent = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM datadump WHERE 'pickup_time' >= '%s' AND 'pickup_time' <= '%s';") data = session.execute(stateMent, (fromdate, todate))

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `SELECT` in the batch statement - it's only for `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`...

Also, please note that BATCH in CQL is different than in SQL, and you need to know when to use it, and when not - please refer to [the documentation on how & when to use it](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply. So I must prepare the statement and then execute it. some thing like this? stateMent = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM datadump WHERE 'pickup_time' >= '%s' AND 'pickup_time' <= '%s';")
    data = session.execute(stateMent, (fromdate, todate))

Comment: if it's just one execution, then version with prepare will be slow, as query need to be sent to server for analysis. But if you're doing often, then you need to prepare query - it will be much more effective

Comment: But actually, you need to spend some time on the learning how Cassandra works, and how to build effective data model. For example, you can use range queries only on clustering columns, and only with specification of partition keys. I recommend to watch DS201 & DS220 courses on https://academy.datastax.com/

Comment: OK I will get it started then :) thank you so much Alex.